# time series group by and filter in dplyr r

Tags: r, filter, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to find specific patterns in groups within a dataframe. Take the following dataframe of orders placed, by email, the person placing the order, and the amount.

```
set.seed(123)
dates = sample(seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"),as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = 'day'), 2000, replace = TRUE)
amount <- sample(-50:100, 2000, replace = TRUE)
placedorder <- sample(c(NA, NA, NA, "jeff", "alex", "steve", "amy", "john", "larry", "ryan"), 2000, replace = TRUE)
email <- sample(paste0(1:200, "@gmail.com"), 2000, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(dates, email, placedorder, amount, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to find groups **by email address** where all three of these occur, *and* where they occur in date succession:

1. An order was placed with a **positive** value and where `placedorder` is NA
2. An order was placed after the above step, with a **negative** value and where `placedorder` is NA
3. An order was placed after the step 2, with a **positive** value and where `placeholder` is *not* NA

**example:**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   email [1]
        dates       email placedorder amount
       <date>       <chr>       <chr>  <int>
 1 2017-02-10 1@gmail.com        <NA>     68 # satisfies #1
 2 2017-02-27 1@gmail.com        <NA>    -21 # satisfies #2
 3 2017-03-07 1@gmail.com        jeff     -9
 4 2017-03-09 1@gmail.com       steve    -93
 5 2017-03-14 1@gmail.com       steve     22 # satisfies #3
 6 2017-03-18 1@gmail.com       steve    -81
 7 2017-04-28 1@gmail.com        <NA>    -12
 8 2017-05-06 1@gmail.com        <NA>      4
 9 2017-06-03 1@gmail.com        jeff    -40
10 2017-06-03 1@gmail.com       larry     13 #(this also satisfies #3)
```

the above example is all within the same `email`, and each of the 3 filters happen one after another with respect to time.

My attempt, I think finds where these occur, but doesn't take into account the dates and this happening in succession. Also, actually filtering it down to just these orders, would be best.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(email) %>%
  filter(any(is.na(placedorder) & amount > 0),
         any(is.na(placedorder) & amount < 0),
         any(!is.na(placedorder) & amount > 0)
  )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A few questions. You are talking about temporal succession when you are saying "after" or just as per the data set row number? In case it is temporal, sort the data set for date and email first (sort email to save on calculation time). Secondly, do you want to filter so that all three conditions are satisfied simultaneously? Also if your problem arises from your date being POSIXct, you might want to convert it to character and back again as per your need, that is messy, but easier to debug later (if commented).

Comment: I meant "after" as in it took place on a date after the first occurrence. I do want to filter so that all three conditions are satisfied simultaneously within a given group, and happen on dates that occur after one another (could be any distance between the dates, just has to be after)

Comment: edited post to show example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming my interpretation of "first order" and "second order" is correct, here's one way to set up the commands in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(email) %>% 
  arrange(email, dates) %>% 
  mutate(order_num=1:n()) %>% 
  #An order was placed with a positive value and where placedorder is NA
  filter((is.na(placedorder) & amount>0) |
  # An order was placed after the first one, with a negative value and where placedorder is NA
         (is.na(placedorder) & amount <0 & order_num >1) |
  # An order was placed after the second order, with a positive value and where placeholder is not NA
        (!is.na(placedorder) & amount >0 & order_num > 2)
    )
```

UPDATE:
Thank you very much for clarifying the question. Basically you want to "watch the customer state" and start tracing next type of event only after you have observed the previous type. Here's a (slightly verbose, but hopefully understandable) attempt at tracing the customer transitioning through these "states":

```
df %>% group_by(email) %>% 
  arrange(email, dates) %>% 
  mutate(event_1=ifelse(is.na(placedorder) & amount>0, 1, 0),
         post_event_1=cumsum(event_1),
         # only if at least one event_1 has happened
         event_2=ifelse(post_event_1>=1 & is.na(placedorder) & amount <0, 1,0),
         post_event_2=cumsum(event_2),
         # only if at least one event_2 has happened
         event_3=ifelse(post_event_2>=1 & !is.na(placedorder) & amount >0, 1, 0)) %>% 
  # only interested in first occurance of event_1 and event_2 preceding event_3
  filter((event_1==1 & post_event_1==1) | (event_2==1 & post_event_2==1) | event_3 ==1)

# A tibble: 390 x 9
# Groups:   email [165]
        dates         email placedorder amount event_1 post_event_1 event_2 post_event_2 event_3
       <date>         <chr>       <chr>  <int>   <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2017-01-29   1@gmail.com        <NA>     76       1            1       0            0       0
 2 2017-05-25   1@gmail.com        <NA>    -37       0            1       1            1       0
 3 2017-08-14   1@gmail.com       steve     53       0            1       0            2       1
 4 2017-12-21   1@gmail.com        john     92       0            2       0            4       1
 5 2017-02-08 100@gmail.com        <NA>     89       1            1       0            0       0
 6 2017-01-16 101@gmail.com        <NA>     40       1            1       0            0       0
 7 2017-03-18 102@gmail.com        <NA>     20       1            1       0            0       0
 8 2017-05-16 102@gmail.com        <NA>    -45       0            2       1            1       0
 9 2017-06-08 102@gmail.com       larry     46       0            2       0            2       1
10 2017-07-22 102@gmail.com        john     93       0            3       0            2       1
# ... with 380 more rows
```

There are some "uncompleted chains" e.g. when customer progressed to state_1 but not further. Not sure if you want to drop those (for that you could count observations per email and drop those that have less than 3 records).

Comment: thanks @dmi3kno. So first - I would need to group by email. It has to happen within the same email. But on top of that I think I didn't clarify "first order" and "second order". There could be 20 orders that happen on days 1 through 20 of november. I want to find instances where occurrence 1 happens, then 2 then 3 on any given dates, but the dates have to come after one another.

Comment: I suppose the OP wants & instead of |, judging by his comment. Excellent answer BTW.

Comment: yeah I do want and, _but_  also the `order_num` doesn't work. I've added more clarification in my post that gives a bit more detail!

Comment: Sorting by dates and then adding the helper column of order numbers does the trick you need, basically.

Comment: @MattW. Add a helper column with `df$ORDER_NUM <- seq(1:nrow(df))` before running the rest of the code. Then, you would not need the `mutate` part.